# Getting mysql error Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_2114_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

i repair all tables even create new but none of them help me to fix it.

this is the query i created

```
SELECT books_history.title, books_history.autor, books_history.rating,
books_history.asin, books_history.link, books_history.cat_1,
books_history.cat_2, reduced_book_test.book_asin FROM books_history,
reduced_book_test where books_history.cat_1 = 'Action & Abenteuer' OR
books_history.cat_2 = 'Action & Abenteuer' AND books_history.asin =
reduced_book_test.book_asin ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

i am not sure if its correct or not if anyone can help me its really help full.

here is the structure of two tables i am using.[image: table book_history][image: reduced_book_test]

what i want is create mysql query so i can get result like this there are two tables book_history, reduced_book_test the common column is  book_history.asin and reduced_book_test.book_asin and i need filter with category from book_history.cat_1 and book_history.cat_2.

please help me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the primary key of parent table as common field in join condition.
All you have to do is Set a primary key for your parent table even if it is 'asin' and use this field also in your child/dependant table and select on the basis of this field.

```
SELECT books_history.title, books_history.autor, books_history.rating,
books_history.asin, books_history.link, books_history.cat_1, 
books_history.cat_2, reduced_book_test.book_asin 
FROM books_history 
inner join reduced_book_test 
on books_history.asin = reduced_book_test.book_asin 
where books_history.cat_1 = 'Action & Abenteuer' 
OR books_history.cat_2 = 'Action & Abenteuer'  
ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: yes this work thank you very much but can you help me on one more thing now result just came and i found that there are many duplicate entry in books_history i mean same asin and other thing can i get only get one when there is duplicate result.

Comment: try DISTINCTROW  after SELECT
i.e SELECT DISTINCTROW ------